# Install Visual Studio & SQL Server on the EC2 Instance aws

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, amazon-ec2

How do I install Visual Studio and SQL Server on the same AWS EC2 instance?

Any idea/suggestion would be highly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by 'Install Visual Studio'?

Answer (score -1):

@Pradeep,

You can provision EC2 instance with SQL Server installed already from AWS console. However you need to install visual studio separately. I did some research in AWS marketplace and Community but did not find any solution where both SQL Server and Visual studio are configured as any AMI or any other solution.

Thanks.
Tarun